# How can I style all <li> except for the fifth and sixth using nth-child()

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have a simple list:

```
<ul>
    <li>Test</li>
    <li>Test1</li>
    <li>Test2</li>
    <li>Test3</li>
    <li>Test4</li>
    <li>Test5</li>
    <li>Test6</li>
    <li>Test7</li>
</ul>
```

I'd like to give all `<li>` a color of red except for the 5 + 6

http://jsfiddle.net/7yDGg/1/

Can this be done using only one selector?

Comment: Do you count this as one selector? http://jsfiddle.net/7yDGg/3/

Comment: wouldn't it just be easier to create two style classes?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use css selector `:not(target)` to explicitly select which child is going to be excluded. replace the `target` with another selector.

We can combine selector `:not()` and `:nth-child()` to exclude specific elements.

For example in this case, we want to exclude the 5th and 6th element, then use this: `:not(:nth-child(5))` and `:not(:nth-child(6))`.

```css
ul li:not(:nth-child(5)):not(:nth-child(6)) {
    color: red; 
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>Test 1</li>
    <li>Test 2</li>
    <li>Test 3</li>
    <li>Test 4</li>
    <li>Test 5</li>
    <li>Test 6</li>
    <li>Test 7</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: @noval First time seeing this filter :) great share !

Comment: Care because it doesn't work with IE < 9 and older versions of FF http://caniuse.com/#search=%3Anot

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is this:

```
ul li {
    color: red;
}
ul li:nth-child(5), ul li:nth-child(6) {
    color: black;
}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7yDGg/4/) updated.